# GeoTools: SimpleFeatureCollection to KML error CoordinateReferenceSystem

Tags: kml, features, geotools, mysql, wgs84

I want to export a SimpleFeatureCollection (Read from a MySQL DB) to a KML file, here is my code used to read the infos into the console:

```
private void featureCollectionToKML(SimpleFeatureCollection features)
        throws Exception {

    Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
    encoder.setIndenting(true);
    encoder.encode(features, KML.kml, System.out);
}
```

When I run the program there are first some WARNINGS when I get the Features and then the program crashes with this error log:

> PM org.geotools.referencing.factory.PropertyAuthorityFactory
>
> WARNING: Axis elements found in a wkt definition, the force longitude
>   first axis order hint might not be respected: PROJCS["Google
>   Projection",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System
>   1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563,
>   AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",
>   0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Popular
>   Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
>   AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]],PARAMETER["semi_minor",
>   6378137.0],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0],PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0],PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0],PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0],PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0],UNIT["m", 1.0]]
>
> ott 23, 2013 4:06:49 PM
>   org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder add
>
> WARNING: Creating LookAt with null CoordinateReferenceSystem - did you
>   mean to setCRS?
>
> ott 23, 2013 4:06:49 PM
>   org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder add
>
> WARNING: Creating Region with null CoordinateReferenceSystem - did you
>   mean to setCRS? java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: id
>     at
>   org.geotools.xml.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:105)
>     at
>   org.geotools.xml.impl.BindingWalker$BindingExecutionChain.execute(BindingWalker.java:220)
>     at org.geotools.xml.impl.BindingWalker.walk(BindingWalker.java:186)
>     at
>   org.geotools.xml.impl.BindingVisitorDispatch.walk(BindingVisitorDispatch.java:47)
>     at
>   org.geotools.xml.impl.BindingVisitorDispatch.walk(BindingVisitorDispatch.java:32)
>     at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:902)    at
>   org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:603)     at
>   shapefileManager.ShapefileManager.featureCollectionToKML(ShapefileManager.java:173)
>     at
>   shapefileManager.ShapefileManager.convertArchiToFeatuesKML(ShapefileManager.java:114)
>     at Main.Test.main(Test.java:19) Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException   at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.getID(ContentFeatureCollection.java:492)
>     at
>   org.geotools.kml.bindings.FeatureTypeBinding.getProperty(FeatureTypeBinding.java:284)
>     at
>   org.geotools.xml.impl.GetPropertyExecutor.visit(GetPropertyExecutor.java:103)
>     ... 9 more

I can't understand which is the problem...

Here is how I get the SimpleFeaturesCollection from MySQL DB

```
 public void convertArcsToFeatuesKML(String[] ids) {

    try {


        FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();

        Set<FeatureId> fids = new HashSet<FeatureId>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

            fids.add(ff.featureId(ids[i]));

        }

        Filter filter = ff.id(fids);

        SimpleFeatureCollection features = featureSource
                .getFeatures(filter);

        this.featureCollectionToKML(features);

    } catch (Exception e) {             e.printStackTrace();        } 
}
```

FeatureSource is the MySQL DB.

PS I've checked, with the getId() method, and all features have an unique ID.

Comment: Looks like you don't have an ID defined - can you print out a couple of features before you call toKML

Comment: I've printed feature.getId() and all have one.

Comment: Your features don't have a CRS set, you need to fix the database tables